# Remove port binding from an existing docker container

Tags: docker

Currently I have a container created with

```
docker run --detach --name gitlab_app --restart=always --publish 192.168.0.200:80:80 --publish 192.168.0.200:22:22 --volumes-from gitlab_data gitlab_image
```

I want to remove both port bindings `80` and `22` from the image. Is it possible to remove port binding from an existing docker container?

NB: It is okay to take the container offline for removing the binding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If its ok for the container to be offline why not just remove and run again without the port switches?

If you do need to do this without deleting containers you could just modify the underlying iptables changes.

```
# Will list the rules
iptables -L

# Will delete the rule you want to remove
iptables --delete [chain] <Rule definition>
```

In general your data should always be in one of 3 places

1. A data only container that can be linked with a restarted service container.
2. A volume defined in your service container than can be linked with a new container to take backups. See [here](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/#backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes) for an example.
3. In a host mounted volume so that you can restart containers and mount the same location into new containers.

With one of these three approaches restarting services becomes easily and this should be standard as micro-services should be designed such that they can go down and recover often. These approaches will also speed up your application as the default union file system is slower than normal file systems which are used for volumes.

If you need to recover data from a container where you did not plan volumes properly you can use the docker export functionality to export the state of your container. Then import it into a new container with a host mounted volume. Copy your critical data from inside the container to the volume.

Comment: In this case, I deleted the old container and created a new one because gitlab stores data in a data container. But if the container has modifications, how can I ensure that the new container will have the changes?

Comment: Updating answer as this is too long for a comment.